# Google Classroom - Add students using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-classroom, google-apps-for-education

There is 1 domain with a subdomain - school.com & students.school.com respectively.

I have created google classrooms for each class using google apps script.

Now comes the problem,
I am trying to add teachers & students into the google classrooms.
The 'super admin' account i am using is with my main domain (school.com).

Therefore, I can add teachers into classrooms, but I cant add students into the classroom because it belongs to the subdomain (students.school.com)

Here's how my code looks like,

```
function addTeachers() {
  Classroom.Courses.Teachers.create({
    userId: "teacher1@school.com",
  }, "123456789");
}

function addStudents() {
  Classroom.Courses.Students.create({
    userId: "student@students.school.com",
  }, "123456789");
}
```

When I run `addStudents` function, this error appears,

```
Execution failed: The caller does not have permission
```

Comment: Not posting as a comment because I realize it's not part of GAS directly, but you can use external tools with the APIs and service accounts to do what you're looking for by impersonating the student and adding to the course using the course enrollment code. See if [this explanation](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gshell-discuss/RQZ7xr1_j9w/OzmYeA1oAwAJ) helps. You may not be able to do service accounts in GAS, but [this may help you go in the right direction](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4443).

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure the domains have [whitelisted each other](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6173514?hl=en) and allowed users from the other domain to be added to courses.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both domains have already whitelisted each other. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Classroom were the classes/teacher are in one domain, and the students are in another. Setup a service account in the students domain. Then delegate domain-wide authority to the service account, with the needed scopes, which should be

auth/classroom.rosters

auth/classroom.profile.emails

auth/classroom.profile.photos

and use that service account to  do the courses.students.create method on behalf on the student's google account (aka using both the courseid and enrollmentCode.)

Comment: Ok, sometime after February 16, 2017, this stopped working.

I now seem to be unable as the Domain Administrator create and accept Google Classroom invites at all.

For now the most i can do i add myself as a teacher to the classroom, send an invite, then remove myself.

I am looking into using a service account that has been Delegated domain-wide authority to both of my school's domains, and do the sending of the invite while impersonated as the teacher, and accept the invite sent to the student while impersonating them.

Comment: 0
down vote
I had the same issue too with teachers in one domain and students in a subdomain. To work around that issue I created student invites for each student in the course, store the ids, and accept the invites by id for each the student.

Comment: I've corrected my answer with a solution I'm using via gShell +0.10.3