# How to add a teacher to all Classroom Courses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

Google Classroom API lists several code examples for adding a teacher to courses based on courseId and teacher email. But none of the [examples](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-users) are in Google Apps Script.

Our school admin does not code, so I'd like to provide him a turn-key solution in GAS (that I understand) but can't test because I'm not admin.

The end goal is to add the same teacher account to all classrooms so we can use that to pull assignment data and support students by helping them stay organized, especially now that we're all online due to Covid19.

If I loop over this and provide an error catch, will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338949/google-classroom-add-students-using-apps-script) work, if run from an admin account?

```
function addTeachers() {
  Classroom.Courses.Teachers.create({
    userId: "teacher@ourdomain.org",
  }, "123456789");
}
```

Comment: I have a solution for you, I'm just digging it out now. There are a few issues with this 'turn-key' solution however, 1. is that if you become a teacher of a very large number of classes then the classroom dashboard becomes very slow / unresponsive. 2. The admin will become a member of **every** active classroom in the domain, depending on the country you live in this could be illegal and a breach of privacy. Is there any particular reason why the teachers can be asked to invite the admin?

Comment: Thanks, James, for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code would work assuming you're using the correct course ID and you enabled the Classroom [Advance Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services), here it's the template code:

```
function addTeachers() {
  Classroom.Courses.Teachers.create({
    userId: "[TEACHER-EMAIL]"
  }, "[COURSE-ID]");
}
```

There could still be errors even if you run it with a G Suite admin depending of certain factors (e.g. if the teacher you're trying to add is already a student in that course). In the [Teachers.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.teachers/create) request documentation is explained some of the possible errors.